ps: invalid option -- 'p'
I'm using Yocto Project (honister) to build my OS image. When I'm trying to use vscode ssh extension, I'm getting an error:
> ps: invalid option -- 'p'
> BusyBox v1.34.1 () multi-call binary.Usage: ps
> Exec server process not found

Any ideas? What can I install? Is there any other ps implementation?

What happens here is that your client (so, the SSH extension?) seems to be calling ps -p. However, the ps in your image doesn't have that flag.
An easy solution would be to actually add a procps layer to your image, and to disable ps as shell-builtin in busybox (the config option is called CONFIG_PS, you can probably set that that to =n in your busybox recipe).

Thanks! My problem is solved :)

@YoctoDragon if this answer helped you best, please accept it ✓ to show your thanks

I'd guess that ps is symlinked to busybox binary in this image, and busybox doesn't implement every flag that ps does.  It is just "good enough" for most tasks.

@Criggie it's a shell built-in, iirc
